# Explain color profiles to me please

Tags: pdf, color-profile

I'm dynamically building PDFs with Perl.  I've been instructed to make all my pdfs use CMYK instead of RGB and that I should use color profiles to do it.  I understand what colorspace is and how to do the conversion but I dont understand why.  Can someone explain color profiles?

I think the following is the same question asked 3 different ways:

1. I understand that the printer print with Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, blacK instead of Red, Green, Blue.  But why does that matter?  Surely printers can convert between CMYK and RGB with a formula?
2. I don't understand how using color profiles during the converstion from CMYK to RGB helps.  Surely there is one formula for converting from RGB to CMYK?  Why is it good to specify a RGB color profile and a CMYK color profile?
3. What is in a color profile file?  Why is it binary?  Why is it so big (ISOcoated_v2_eci.icc is 1.8Mb)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printers can convert between CMYK and RGB. They *do* have a formula. The problem is they all have a different one :)

Seriously though, this topic is very broad, and not really programming related. Reading a book or basic tutorial might work best. Wikipedia can  give some first aid:

- [CMYK Color model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK)
- [ICC Profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_profile)
- [Color management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_management)
- Oh, and a nice one on the graphic design SE: [What are color profiles?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/114/what-are-color-profiles)

Also, Googling `introduction to color management` turns up some interesting-looking tutorials like [this one](http://www.drycreekphoto.com/Learn/color_management.htm).

if you have some more detailed questions, I'd say the right place for most of them is [Graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks so much!  I guess it is a bit off topic.